# Hiding element before document is ready?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, html

I have a div that needs to be hidden by default. It then can be toggled by a button:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function toggle() {
            text = document.getElementById('add_view');
            var isHidden = text.style.display == 'none';
            text.style.display = isHidden ? 'block' : 'none';
        }


        $(document).ready
    (

              function () {
                  toggle();
                  $("#add_view, #btnToggle").click(function (e) {
                      e.stopPropagation();
                  });
                  $(document).click(function () {
                      toggle();
                  });
              }
    );


</script>
```

It is working fine. The only problem is, when I refresh the page, I momentarily see the div before it is hidden.

What could I do to prevent that?

Thanks

Comment: don't forget to mark one of the answers as correct if you're happy with any

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You probably need to hide your element by default, and then use the button to toggle visibility. Try this:

```
<div id="add_view" style="display:none">....</div>
```

Comment: It's quite frustrating to be the first to answer a question and have less points than the others

Comment: Thanks @RobertNiestroj, this happens a lot of times here in SO. If 2 answers are the same, I only upvote the first one to give the answer, I think this way it's fair. You can easily see the exact answer time by hovering on the part that says: `answered xx mins ago`

Comment: Did not knew that with the exact time

Answer (score 8):

Make the element hidden in your html to begin with.

```
<div id="add_view" style="display: none;"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Initially, you have to hide it by setting `style="display:none;"` of the div.                Once when u want to toggle it, you have to use it as

```
document.getElementById(Id).style.display="";
```

in javascript.